# Rails3 Beta4 Devise Delayed_job configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, devise

I want to use delayed_job to send email in backend, this is 
/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587, 
    :domain               => DOMAIN,  
    :user_name            => USERNAME,  
    :password             => PASSWORD,  
    :authentication       => "plain",  
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

so I want to know how to configure the delayed_job to send mail in backend.Thank you.

Comment: Nobody knows?
Who can give me a hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use action mailer tutorial first http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html then just mark your mail for performing in delayed_job:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end

  handle_asynchronously :welcome_email
end
```

You can also call handle asynchronously in config:

```
UserMailer.handle_asynchronously :welcome_email
```

Answer (score 0):

This site walks through the whole process: http://www.magnionlabs.com/2009/2/28/background-job-processing-in-rails-with-delayed_job

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://xponrails.net/2011/03/04/how-to-send-email-asynchronously-using-devise-and-rails3/

Worked for me ...